# How to get minimum value of Enum type declared in function type definition?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I want to define a function that uses one of the constants defined for the given type. I tried:

```
minValue :: (Enum a,Bounded a) => a
minValue = minBound::a
```

but the function definition doesn't know that a is of type Enum, because that is specified in the declaration.

Answer (score 7):

Two plausible answers:

1. Delete the internal type signature.

   ```
   minValue = minBound
   ```

   While this works, it doesn't "scale" well to larger functions that need to do more stuff, where it may not be so obvious which type to use for `minBound`. That leads us to
2. Turn on lexical scoping for type variables. You can start a scope with the `forall` keyword; then definitions in that scope can refer to type variables. Thus:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
   minValue :: forall a. (Enum a, Bounded a) => a
   minValue = minBound :: a
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting here is `ScopedTypeVariables`, where the `a` in `minValue`'s type signature is the same as the `a` used in the definition.  However, I have a suspicion that you don't need it for your use case.  The value `minBound` is polymorphic, and when something in Haskell is polymorphic it's usually *call site* polymorphic.  This means that the caller determines the type, not the definition.  For example, you could write something like

```
cycleBounded :: (Bounded a, Enum a, Eq a) => [a]
cycleBounded
    = minBound
    : map (\n -> if n == maxBound then minBound else succ n)
          cycleBounded
```

And then you could do something like `cycleBounded :: [Bool]` to get something equivalent to `cycle [False, True]`.  However, you would run into a problem if you wanted to get rid of the `Eq` constraint by using `fromEnum` on `n` and `maxBound` before comparing, because then the compiler doesn't know what `Bounded a => a` to use for `maxBound`, there's nothing in the context that says that it has to use the same type as `n`, just that it's a `(Enum a, Bounded a) => a`.  This would be an appropriate application of `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

cycleBounded :: forall a. (Bounded a, Enum a, Eq a) => [a]
cycleBounded
    = minBound
    : map (\n -> if fromEnum n == fromEnum (maxBound :: a) then minBound else succ n)
          cycleBounded
```

And while there are tricks to get these types to unify without the need for `ScopedTypeVariables`, most would probably find it more understandable to see `ScopedTypeVariables` and `maxBound :: a` than anything.  For the sake of completeness, here's how you could get it to unify:

```
cycleBounded
    = minBound
    : map (\n -> let {m = maxBound;
                      x = [m, n] -- This forces `m` and `n` to have the same type
                     }
                 in if fromEnum n == fromEnum (head x)
                        then minBound
                        else succ n)
          cycleBounded
```

Which is pretty ugly in my opinion.